# Jquery "get it" obtaining recursive values from a recursive PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, recursion

I have this PHP script that reads and prints my directories from my path. This script is working fine. The problem is the jquery "get id" is geting the "recusive value" from this printed result. I do not have any idea how it is happening but he is taking the value from "all loopings" created from PHP recursive fucntion. It is a simple "default" recursive php function:

```
<?php
function listIt($path) {
$items = scandir($path);

foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    if($item != "." and $item != ".." and $item !=".git" ) {
        if (is_file($path ."\\". $item)) {
            // nothing here
        } else {
            // the recursive item is here
            echo "<div  id='".$key.$path."/".$item."' class='togleFolder' togleFolder' style='padding-left: 25px'>";
                echo $item;
                listIt($path ."\\". $item);
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
  }
}
echo "<div style='padding-left: 10px'>";
listIt(getcwd());
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Jquery script is even simpler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".togleFolder").click(function(){
        let myId= $(this).attr("id");
        console.log ("myId: "+myId);
    });
});
```

and finally the HTML output:

```html
<div style="padding-left: 10px">
 <div id="3C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson/My-Models" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">My-Models</div>
 <div id="5C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson/app" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
 app<div id="2C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\app/Http" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
 Http<div id="2C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\app\Http/Controllers" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
Controllers</div>
<div id="3C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\app\Http/Request" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
Request</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="9C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson/dump" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
dump</div>
<div id="15C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson/open-iconic" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
 open-iconic<div id="7C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic/font" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
 font<div id="2C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic\font/css" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
css</div>
<div id="3C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic\font/fonts" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
fonts</div>
</div>
<div id="8C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic/open-iconic-master" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
 open-iconic-master<div id="7C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic\open-iconic-master/font" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
 font<div id="2C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic\open-iconic-master\font/css" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
css</div>
<div id="3C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic\open-iconic-master\font/fonts" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
fonts</div>
</div>
<div id="9C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic\open-iconic-master/png" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
png</div>
<div id="10C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic\open-iconic-master/sprite" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
sprite</div>
<div id="11C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic\open-iconic-master/svg" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
svg</div>
<div id="12C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic\open-iconic-master/webp" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
webp</div>
</div>
<div id="10C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic/png" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
png</div>
<div id="11C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic/sprite" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
sprite</div>
<div id="12C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic/svg" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
svg</div>
<div id="13C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson\open-iconic/webp" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
webp</div>
</div>
<div id="17C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson/routes" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">
routes</div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="9C:\Apache24\htdocs\FuryJson/dump" class="togleFolder" style="padding-left: 25px">dump</div>
```

So it is giving me a lots of recursives values instead the only one. 
Sorry if I did not make myself clear, it is because it is a really hard question.Thanks

Comment: ok see the console for the rendered html code , and copy/paste it here .. not all of it .. just one `div` printed from inside the loop

Comment: It is edited, I try to format the HTML code but I think it could make even weird to look, by the way, at loooking the output i though this hierachy divs that is giving the error, What do you think?

Comment: 1st: comment `//listIt($path ."\\". $item);` .. 2nd: use `data-id= ` instead of `id=` then on js `var myId= $(this).attr("data-id");` instead of `let myId= $(this).attr("id");` .. And `class='togleFolder' togleFolder'` should be `class='togleFolder'`

Comment: when I comment the //listIt() function I lost the recursive function that gives the subdirectories